# Meetup oauth2: API replies with invalid_client

Tags: node.js, oauth, oauth-2.0, passport.js, meetup

I aim to add Meetup oauth2 to [Open Collective](https://OpenCollective.com), a Node.js server using Passport. (I previously succeeded with GitHub oauth2, so in principle it's just about adding the [Passport strategy](https://github.com/joewoodhouse/passport-meetup-oauth2) `passport-meetup-oauth2`.)

To avoid any issues about using localhost (issue observed in other SO tickets), I used an HTTPS ngrok tunnel. On Meetup.com I [created](https://www.meetup.com/meetup_api/auth/#oauth2) a new consumer with:

- Redirect URI: https://e03857fc.ngrok.io (also tried with the full callbackURL mentioned below, same results)
- Website: left empty (also tried same value as Redirect URI, same results)

In my code, I configured the MeetupStrategy with:

- clientID: "Key" shown on my Meetup "Your OAuth Consumers" page
- clientSecret: "Secret" shown on my Meetup "Your OAuth Consumers" page
- callbackURL: "https://e03857fc.ngrok.io/connected-accounts/meetup/callback"

I then try the flow: I'm redirected correctly to Meetup.com where I'm requested to log in and click "Allow", then I'm redirected back to my server, but Passport issues a [500 TokenError](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-oauth2/blob/master/lib/strategy.js#L320):

`{ TokenError
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (~/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:321:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (~/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:368:16)
    at ~/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:167:45
    at ~/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:181:18
    at passBackControl (~/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:123:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (~/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:143:7)
    at emitNone (events.js:91:20)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (events.js:185:7)
    at endReadableNT (_stream_readable.js:934:12)
    at _combinedTickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:74:11)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:98:9)
  name: 'TokenError',
  message: undefined,
  code: 'invalid_client',
  uri: undefined,
  status: 500 }`

The error is raised by the second oauth2 step (exchanging `authorization_code` for `access_token`): Passport calls the Meetup API, which replies with HTTP 400 `Bad Request` `{"error":"invalid_client"}`. Having added logs in the [oauth lib](https://github.com/ciaranj/node-oauth/blob/master/lib/oauth2.js#L176), I can reproduce the Meetup invalid_client error as follows:

`curl -v -X POST https://secure.meetup.com/oauth2/access -H "'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'" --data "grant_type=authorization_code&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fe03857fc.ngrok.io%2Fconnected-accounts%2Fmeetup%2Fcallback&client_id=XXX&client_secret=YYY&code=ZZZ"`

It looks like the issue is on the Meetup side as I can reproduce it with curl, and the client ID and secret seem correct. Any idea what's causing the error?

Comment: Try to have an exact match beween the redirect uri in the configuration and the callback url you provide. The provider could be oversensitive about this mismatch you have.

Comment: Yes that's what I first tried, then I only left the base URL as per the Meetup instructions: "You may enter a base url to get the maximum use out of this consumer". Same error in both cases.

Comment: And the very first request where you redirect the browser? Is it the same as the one you POST in the second step?

Comment: Good that you made me check that in detail, I wasn't passing the callbackURL in the second call! Github wasn't requesting this.

Comment: Does it work now then?

Comment: Yes, thanks :) (It's a separate issue but I now just have trouble passing exactly the same callbackURL both times --wanted to pass some encrypted data in its params, and if I re-encrypt for the second call it won't be the exact same string. Need to set up some temporary memory map...)